# implementation of complex numbers

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, methods, complex-numbers

I have this part of a code that I need to implement or modify the necessary methods in the class so that the program produces the following output.

```
c1 = 1+2i 
c2 = 3-4i 
c3 = -5 
c4 = 6i
c5 = -7i
c6 = 0
c1 + c2 = 4-2i
c1 - c2 = -2+6i
c1 * c2 = 11+2i 
conjugate of c1 = 1-2i
```

The implementation of the Complex class, representing complex number, is missing. The attributes of a complex number are, obviously, its real part and its imaginary part (floats) and do not need to be protected attributes. but I have no idea how to implement this in order to get the output above.

so far what I have:

code:

```
class Complex:
    def __init__(self, real, imag):
        self.real = real
        self.imag = imag

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.real) + "+" + str(self.imag) + "i"


def main():
    c1 = Complex(1, 2)
    print("c1 =", c1)
    c2 = Complex(3, -4)
    print("c2 =", c2)
    c3 = Complex(-5, 0)
    print("c3 =", c3)
    c4 = Complex(0, 6)
    print("c4 =", c4)
    c5 = Complex(0, -7)
    print("c5 =", c5)
    c6 = Complex(0, 0)
    print("c6 =", c6)
    print("c1 + c2 =", c1 + c2)
    print("c1 - c2 =", c1 - c2)
    print("c1 * c2 =", c1 * c2)
    c7 = c1.conjugate()
    print("conjugate of c1 =", c7)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

`def main()` cannot be changed

output:

```
c1 = 1+2i
c2 = 3+-4i
c3 = -5+0i
c4 = 0+6i
c5 = 0+-7i
c6 = 0+0i
```

Comment: Why don't you use numpy for this? Because here you only create strings, you won't be able to add anything with it.

Comment: @Panda50 unfortunately I'm unable to use imports

Comment: is your question to re-implement the complex numbers? Otherwise you can use the builtin complex numbers `1+2j` etc. Python like some other languages use `j` as the imaginary unit, in contrast to math where usually a lowercase 'i' is used.

Comment: @Panda50 its kinda a math based problem using methods.. but I'm not really good with maths

Comment: @TerhorstD I think is to use the builtin complex numbers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the builtin complex numbers for exactly that. Python like some other languages use `j` as the imaginary unit, in contrast to math where usually a lowercase `i` is used.

```py
def main():
    c1 = 1+2j
    print("c1 =", c1)
    c2 = 3-4j
    print("c2 =", c2)
    c3 = -5+0j
    print("c3 =", c3)
    c4 = 0+6j
    print("c4 =", c4)
    c5 = 0-7j
    print("c5 =", c5)
    c6 = 0+0j
    print("c6 =", c6)
    print("c1 + c2 =", c1 + c2)
    print("c1 - c2 =", c1 - c2)
    print("c1 * c2 =", c1 * c2)
    c7 = c1.conjugate()
    print("conjugate of c1 =", c7)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

which gives the output:

```
c1 = (1+2j)
c2 = (3-4j)
c3 = (-5+0j)
c4 = 6j
c5 = -7j
c6 = 0j
c1 + c2 = (4-2j)
c1 - c2 = (-2+6j)
c1 * c2 = (11+2j)
conjugate of c1 = (1-2j)
```

If you are fine with the additional parenthesis, you are done. Otherwise, you can do output formatting for example like this:

```py
print(f"conjugate of c7 = {c7.real}{c7.imag:+}j")
```

EDIT:
In case your `main()` method requires the use of the `Complex` class, you can just wrap the built-ins:

```py
class Complex(complex):
    pass
```

This works because your `Complex` class has the same prototype as the builtin `complex` data type. You can even overload the `__str__(self)` as you proposed and it works whenever the `str()` is requested. So the `Complex` class could look like this:

```py
class Complex(complex):
    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.real) + "+" + str(self.imag) + "i"
```

Comment: this works, but unfortunately the main code ```def main()``` cannot be changed

Comment: so I need to define methods/functions under ``` class Complex``` to perform this

Comment: how can I implement the ```__str__(self)``` method?

Comment: as you proposed it ;)

Comment: I have obtained the code from a classmate, but to prevent plagiarism could you help me rewrite the code?